# Cambiar variable mediante llamada a funcion

Tags: c, funciones, variables, punteros

Necesito saber si esto se puede hacer, creo que con punteros se podria pero no se de que forma. Por un lado tenemos una funcion `cambiarValor`

```
void cambiarValor (int a){
    a=a*4;
}
```

y por otro lado el `main` desde donde la invocamos

```
int main(){
    a=4;
    cambiarValor(a);
}
```

Lo que quiero saber es para que al final del `main` el valor de `a` haya cambiado que punteros tengo que usar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Lo que quiero saber es para que al final del `main` el valor de `a` haya cambiado que punteros tengo que usar

Esto, mejor explicado, quedaría así:

> Lo que quiero saber es qué tengo que modificar en mi código para que cambie el valor de `a`

Y, efectivamente, la solución pasa por usar punteros.

Para empezar, la función `cambiarValor` debe recibir un puntero (es la única forma de conseguir que la función modifique una variable ajena a la propia función):

```
void cambiarValor (int* a){
    *a=(*a)*4;
}
```

Y, finalmente, hay que modificar el `main` para que la variable no se pase por valor sino que ahora a `cambiarValor` le debemos facilitar una referencia a dicha variable:

```
int main(){
    a=4;
    cambiarValor(&a);
}
```